# How to solve HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed ? Handler Verb Error

Tags: php, post, iis, handler

Below is the error I am receiving when trying to execute **php** in **localhost**. Its comes from when I click a form input that then executes the **php** which uses the '**POST**' request. The errors looks like its coming from a handler that doesn't have the **POST** **verb** defined in it. **My questions is, is how do I locate which handler this error is coming from?** . I have had a look at some online resources but none of are using **IIS** or at least the newer versions of it so **its hard to follow.**

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed The page you are looking for
>   cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being
>   used.
>
> Most likely causes: The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP
>   verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the
>   request. A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid
>   HTTP verb. The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb
>   other than GET or HEAD. A request was sent to a virtual directory
>   using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file
>   that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.

Below are the steps the error gives to solve it. I have looked through the logs and found it **definitely** the **POST** request. I am not sure how to create a tracer though.

> Things you can try: Verify the list of verbs enabled for the module
>   handler this request was sent to, and ensure that this verb should be
>   allowed for the Web site. Check the IIS log file to see which verb is
>   not allowed for the request. Create a tracing rule to track failed
>   requests for this `HTTP` status code.

I am aware there are other posts similar to this and I have been through a majority of them with no resolution.

**Thank you in advance.**

- Solved by removing handler and adding it back in the webconfig file with verb="*".

Comment: what kind of web server you are using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have literally just solved it by removing the handler name and adding it back with the verbs set to verb="*" in the web config file.

Comment: if your issue is resolved I request you to post the helpful suggestion and mark that as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found the web config file for the handler the error was related to. I then removed it and added back using verb="*". This sets the handler to accept all verbs including POST which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The error was resolved by adding the following script to web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
      <!-- add this -->
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*."  verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*."  verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"  modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*."  verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"  modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).