# How to diagnose the cause of "HTTP Error 405.0"?

Tags: php, post, iis, http-status-code-405

I have a web app installed on an IIS server that opens an iFrame that points to another app on the exact server, using the same domain/URL.

The iframe is opened via the following code:

```
<form method='post' action='@url' target='myframe' hidden name="iframe_poster" id="iframe_poster">
        <input type='hidden' name="some_variable" value='@some_variable'>
        <input type='hidden' name="some_variable2" value='@some_variable2'>

    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#iframe_poster").submit();
        });
    </script>
```

This results in the following error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
> method (HTTP verb) is being used.

The corresponding IIS log will log the 405 error:

> 2023-07-04 05:11:04 [ip_address] POST /[the_url] 443 - [ip_address]
> Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.2;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
> https://[the_url] **405** 0 1 194

So, somehow this POST request is being denied. But how can i check where this can be changed?

Additional info:

- Post via Ajax call works without issue in the web app loaded into the iframe itself
- If it makes a difference, the web app loaded in the iframe is written in PHP. could there also be a setting in the php.config file?

Comment: Enable FRT to see which module gives you 405, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Very likely you misconfigured IIS/PHP so that the static file handler reports 405, and that's expected.

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.

Comment: HTTP Error 405.0 when you visit a website that is hosted on a server that is running IIS, please refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website 
Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59748806/how-to-solve-http-error-405-0-method-not-allowed-handler-verb-error

Comment: @LexLi FRT shows the 405 error comes from "DefaultDocumentModule". What can i do to resolve it?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide FRT detailed error logs to community members.